# Dynamically create a listview with header rows for each month

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Figuring out how to section a listview is kicking my butt right now.   I've seen the code for sectioned-list-adapter here: [ListView with scrolling/fixed header rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12551926/listview-with-scrolling-fixed-header-rows) and this may be ultimately what I want, but perhaps there's a better way.

Here are the requirements that I need:

- Data for the listview needs to come from an SQLite Database (see code below for table layout)
- Data should be grouped by month (bonus points for month/year)
- header row should contain number of items recorded in the database for that month
- must be compatible with API 8+
- need to be able to click an item to open a dialog containing the moves performed on that day ( I already know how to do this once I can get a list created)

Looking at Jeff Snarkey's seperatedListAdapter here: http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/  I was able to come up with the following:

```
datasource = new SmashDataSource(this);
    datasource.open();
    BJJHistory = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListHistory);

    // create our list and custom adapter
    adapter = new SeparatedListAdapter(this);
    HistoryBJJ = datasource.getBJJHistory();
    // THE DESIRED COLUMNS TO BE BOUND
    final String[] columns = new String[] { SQLiteHelper.DATE };

    // THE XML DEFINED VIEWS WHICH THE DATA WILL BE BOUND TO
    final int[] to = new int[] { R.id.list_item_title };
    if (HistoryBJJ != null) {
        adapter.addSection("October", new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item,
                HistoryBJJ, columns, to));
    }

    BJJHistory.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This uses the following cursor to pull data from the SQLite database in Descending order:

```
public Cursor getBJJHistory() {
    final String[] columns = { SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID, SQLiteHelper.DATE };
    final Cursor History;
    History = database.query(SQLiteHelper.TABLE_BJJ, columns, null, null, null, null,
            SQLiteHelper.DATE + " DESC");
    return History;

}
```

This results in the following:

[image: sample list]

This is fine for a start, but presents me with two problems:

- How to dynamically populate the "Header" value with the month?  I've thought about using a cursor to fill an array with the list of months (after formatting them with a SimpleDateFormat), then doing a For Each loop to go through each one, passing the month back to the cursor method to pull all entries with a datetime value in that month.
- How to display the results in a row as the number of entries for that day?  Ideally I'd like something like this:
  [image: daterow]

The answer for #2 is somewhat simple enough, just put two textviews in the listview row layout, what is more complicated is how to group all rows in the database for each day, or at least do a count for each day and use that count to display in the list.

For the first, going back to the example code here: http://code.google.com/p/android-section-list/, instead of the example array provided, I think I could possibly change the following:

```
SectionListItem[] exampleArray = { // Comment to prevent re-format
new SectionListItem("Test 1 - A", "A"), //
        new SectionListItem("Test 2 - A", "A"), //
        new SectionListItem("Test 3 - A", "A"), //
        new SectionListItem("Test 4 - A", "A"), //
        new SectionListItem("Test 5 - A", "A"), //
        new SectionListItem("Test 6 - B", "B"), //
        new SectionListItem("Test 7 - B", "B"), //
        new SectionListItem("Test 8 - B", "B"), //
        new SectionListItem("Test 9 - Long", "Long section"), //
        new SectionListItem("Test 10 - Long", "Long section"), //
        new SectionListItem("Test 11 - Long", "Long section"), //
        new SectionListItem("Test 12 - Long", "Long section"), //
        new SectionListItem("Test 13 - Long", "Long section"), //
        new SectionListItem("Test 14 - A again", "A"), //
        new SectionListItem("Test 15 - A again", "A"), //
        new SectionListItem("Test 16 - A again", "A"), //
        new SectionListItem("Test 17 - B again", "B"), //
        new SectionListItem("Test 18 - B again", "B"), //
        new SectionListItem("Test 19 - B again", "B"), //
        new SectionListItem("Test 20 - B again", "B"), //
        new SectionListItem("Test 21 - B again", "B"), //
        new SectionListItem("Test 22 - B again", "B"), //
        new SectionListItem("Test 23 - C", "C"), //
        new SectionListItem("Test 24 - C", "C"), //
        new SectionListItem("Test 25 - C", "C"), //
        new SectionListItem("Test 26 - C", "C"), //
```

and replace that with the cursors or what not needed to pull data by day, then instead of "A", "B", "C", replace that with the month name.

This is pretty confusing to me as I'm learning still, I've gotten pretty much every part of this app complete, I just can't figure out how to section the data into a list

As a reference, this is a screenshot of "CardioTrainer", a workout app that has a custom sectioned list, but is basically what I'm trying to duplicate, at least in function.

[image: cardio trainer screenshot]

The table this is coming from looks like this:
[image: datatable]

Comment: First of all, I recommend against using someone else's Adapter when you need to customize your section headers. It's not very difficult at all to implement sections in a list. I just need one thing.. When you retrieve a cursor to the database for displaying, do you pull all the data in order with respect to time? What do you do when there's a change in the year? For example, you show Sections from June to December of 2011, then what should happen when a date from January 2012 comes in?

Answer (score 1):

How about using https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge instead of http://code.google.com/p/android-section-list/.

As i doubt you have a requirement a section should stick at the top while scrolling.

Secondly using merge adapter is simple.

addView(Your Section View)
addAdapter(Your particular section adapter)

This should get you going :)

Hope it helps.